# Angular template syntax assign async array as multiple variables

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

In JS, there's an elegant way to pass values from a given array to new variables like so:

```
let [a, b, c] = [1, 2, 3]; // a = 1, b = 2, c = 3
```

I was wondering if I could achieve the same elegant way using Angular's HTML syntax, something like so:

```
// TS
this.obs1$: Observable<ObsType1> = ...;
this.obs2$: Observable<ObsType2> = ...;
this.combined$ = combineLatest(this.obs1$, this.obs2$);

// HTML
<div *ngIf="combined$ | async as [valOfObs1, valOfObs2]">
    ...
</div>
```

The `combined$` observable is the result of [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html) from RxJS which should return me an array of values of arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there's nothing that implies in the docs that this is possible. Therefore, I had to make a workaround like so:

```
this.obs1$: Observable<ObsType1> = ...;
this.obs2$: Observable<ObsType2> = ...;
this.combined$: Observable<{obs1: ObsType1, obs2:: ObsType2}>;

this.combined$ = combineLatest(this.obs1$, this.obs2$).pipe(
    map(([obs1, obs2]) => ({obs1, obs2});
);

// HTML
<div *ngIf="combined$ | async as combined">
    {{ combined.obs1.foo}}
    {{ combined.obs2.bar}}
</div>
```